# Getting error "Schema Reference ID" when clicking on Update Preview button during inline editing (Tridion UI)

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am able to do inline editing for the Component.
I am able to open the Component in "Form View" and can save the Component, but when I try to click on the "Update Preview" button it prompts with the error "Schema Reference ID".
The same error message is also displayed as warning when I click on "SDL Tridion" tag or refresh the page.

The following errors has been logged in the Tridion Event Viewer:

```
SCHEMA_REFERENCE_ID Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
   Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE StackTrace
   Information Details: at
   Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetList(SystemWideListFilter filter)
   at
   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.GetSystemWideListXml(SystemWideListFilterData
   filter) at SyncInvokeGetSystemWideListXml(Object , Object[] ,
   Object[] ) at
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object
   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
   rpc) at
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
   rpc) at
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
   isOperationContextSet)
```

---

```
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'.
The read operation failed, see inner exception.
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.BeginReadCore(Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.ReadAsyncResult..ctor(IConnection connection, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.StartReading()
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.BeginRead(Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.BeginRead(Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.BeginReceive(TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.PerformOperation(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.SynchronizedAsyncResult`1..ctor(SynchronizedMessageSource syncSource, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.BeginReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult..ctor(FramingDuplexSessionChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.BeginTryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionReceiveChannelGeneric`1.BeginTryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.BeginTryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
```

---

Also New Page and Insert Component options are appearing as disabled. Although I have created one Page Type in Tridion.

Does anyone have a suggestion on what may be causing the issues?

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 6):

The page type may need a browser refresh or cache clearing, as this is heavily cached. Re-opening the browser usually does it for me.

The other issue looks like you may have a mis-configured Session Preview Database (wrong version or not correctly configured in your storage wrappers).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but after reopening the browser still it does not work(New Page option is still disable). For other issue as suggested bu you I will again check my configurations.

Comment: We'll need more info, and you probably should break it down into multiple questions. Read Albert's brilliant troubleshooting guide: http://albertromkes.com/2013/01/24/troubleshooting-the-sdl-tridion-experience-manager-with-session-preview/

Comment: I have checked all my configuration (seems to be correct) but could not able to find the issue. I am still getting error "Schema_Reference_ID" when I click to "Update Preview" button. Thanks

Comment: Wrong database here refers to database version or complete database?

Comment: Either, it's impossible to tell from such a short error and description. Check that the database you are using for Session Preview has the right version. (something along these lines: select DB_VERSION from TDS_DB_INFO). Should be 6.1.0.0

Comment: The version of the database is "6.1.0.0" same as you have mentioned.

Comment: it should be 6.1.0.1 for HR1 AND UI

Comment: Thanks Nuno and Vikas for your help. Upgraded the database for HR1 and issue is now resolved.

Comment: Thanks @vikaskumar - apparently I checked on a SP1 box, not SP1.1 :(